# linux bash: reacting to -c and -[0-9] in a case

Tags: linux, bash, parameters, case

I'm trying to write a script that reacts to the -c input as a parameter. It should print the next parameter in uppercase. 
The second one is an input of -[0-9] where you can give any number from 0 to 9. The next parameter should then be printed as much as the number you entered.

Here's my code:

```
function print_info(){
  echo mijn CPU-type is: $CPU
  echo mijn Totaal beschikbare RAM is: $RAMTOTAAL kB
  echo mijn IP-adres is $IP_ADDR en mijn Default Gateway is: $GW
  echo momenteel is er $RAMUSEDPROCENT % van mijn geheugen in gebruik
}

while :
do
param=1
params=$#
CPU=$(cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep model | grep name | cut -d: -f2)
RAMTOTAAL=$(free | grep Mem | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{ print $1}')
IP_ADDR=$(ifconfig | grep inet | head -1 | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{print $1}')
GW=$(netstat -nr | awk '{print $2}' | head -3 | awk 'NR == 3 { print $1}')
RAMFREE=$(free | grep Mem | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{ print $3}')
RAMUSED=$(free | grep Mem | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{ print $2}')
RAMUSEDPROCENT=$(($RAMUSED*100/$RAMTOTAAL))
counter=1
while [ "$param" -le "$params" ]
do
  case \$$param in
    "-c"   ) shift; echo \$$param zegt je dat | awk '{print toupper($0)}'; print_info;;
    [0-9] ) shift; while [ $counter -lt \$$param ]; do echo \$$param; print_info; done;;
    *      ) eval echo \$$param zegt je dat; print_info;;
  esac
  (( param ++ ))
done
done
```

I hope you guys can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're using positional params incorrectly, and you're attempting to do a double dereference that you can't do. Also, I see that you're using `shift`, but you're using it incorrectly...

The normal way to process positional parameters is, of course, in a loop.

```
set -- echo -c foo 4 test
while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
    case "$1" in
    -c)
        echo second time through the loop, "\$1" == "$1".
        echo also, "\$2" == "$2";
        shift; shift ;;
    [0-9])
        echo third time through, "\$1" == "$1" and "\$2" == "$2"
        : do stuff
        shift; shift ;;
    *)
        echo first time through the loop, "\$1" == "$1"
        shift ;;
    esac
done
```

See how that works out for you.

Comment: oops, forgot a shift. Added now.

Comment: Still the same type of output. It kind of skips the -c and the -[0-9]

Comment: Odd. Copy/paste my above example into a file and run it with `bash filename`, does it work then?

Comment: This works, maybe I'm changing it in a wrong way to match my code. I really don't know what should come where.

Comment: Instead of playing games with `$param` and `$params` and `\$$param`: Use `$1` and `$#`. The `shift` command will discard `$1`, and move `$2` into `$1`, moving the other positional parameters to match, and will decrement $#. Try it again.

Answer (score 1):

or you can use the bash's getopts with error handling and so

```
while getopts ":c:0:1:2:3:4:5:6:7:8:9:" opt;
do
    case $opt in
    c)
        tr "[:lower:]" "[:upper:]" <<<"$OPTARG"
        ;;
    0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9)
        yes "$OPTARG" | head -$opt
        ;;
    \?)
        echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG" >&2
        exit 1
        ;;
    :)
        echo "Option -$OPTARG requires an argument." >&2
        exit 1
        ;;
    esac
done
```

what for the

```
$bash script -c shoud_be_upper -4 four_times
```

will produce

```
SHOUD_BE_UPPER
four_times
four_times
four_times
four_times
```

or alternatively

```
while getopts ":c:0123456789" opt;
do
    case $opt in
    c)
        tr "[:lower:]" "[:upper:]" <<<"$OPTARG"
        ;;
    0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9)
        number=$opt
        ;;
    \?)
        echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG" >&2
        exit 1
        ;;
    :)
        echo "Option -$OPTARG requires an argument." >&2
        exit 1
        ;;
    esac
done

shift $((OPTIND-1))
yes $1 | head -$number
```

what will output the same as above only doesn't check the existence of the parameter after the number

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm misunderstanding something, the documentation I can see seems to indicate that what you're doing should work. Try specifying all the digits as alternate options instead. `0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9 )`

How exactly is it failing?

Comment: Stil not working, but thanks.
In fact what's happening is that it jumps to the *-section and skips the "-c" and [0-9]. It just prints out the -c as is

Comment: And if you drop the `eval` word, what gets echoed? (And what do you see if you run the script with `bash -xv`?)

Comment: without eval I see $1 $2 and so on instead of the effective parameter.
And if I do it with bash -xv I see: [pastebin link](http://pastebin.com/medNkLMw)

Comment: Can you help me? I don't see it right away. I'm still new to linux scripts.